# How to target next class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on the snippet below. Why am I not able to target the first `.help-block` existing in close to `input`?

As you can see I already tried:

```
$(this).parent().find('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
$(this).closest('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
$(this).parent().next('.help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
```

but still not able to target the paragraph.

```js
function txtInput(elem) {
        var inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
        if (inputData == "") {
          $(this).parent().find('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
          $(this).closest('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
          $(this).parent().next('.help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
        }
    }


$(".btn-default").on("click", function(){
    if (txtInput($('#name'))){console.log("It Works");}
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
    <input class="name" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <p class="help-block">help</p>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
```

Comment: Change `$(this)` to `$(elem)` - `this` refers to the button

Comment: Two things, 1, make sure your `find` and `closest` are using proper selectors (you are missing a periond `.` on some of them). 2. Insead of doing $(this).parent()... do $elem.parent()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to use elem instead of this:

```
function txtInput(elem) {
        var inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
        if (inputData == "") {
          $(elem).parent().find('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
          $(elem).closest('help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
          $(elem).parent().next('.help-block').html('Name Field  Can\'t Be Empty!');
        }
    }
```

Just by doing that change it works now.  Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbopmaez/) of it working.